# How to prevent from javascript, Flash navigateToURL?

Tags: javascript, flash

In one of my websites I use third-party flash files, but I want to avoid that the flash file to perform a redirect on my page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to adjust the code of the Flash file itself, I'm afraid you can't prevent it from outside the file (unless the third party file allows you to pass in some settings, but I doubt that's the case).

If you don't want people to interact with the SWF you could try to overlay it with a transparent div so they can't click it anymore, but that's far from ideal.