# Stop iframe from redirecting main page

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to stop an iframe from redirecting the main page. The frame consist of a flash player so sandbox attribute wouldn't work, as it wouldn't load the flash I used on the  parent page.

```
<script>
window.onbeforeunload = function(){
    return false; // This will stop the redirecting.
} </script>
```

It works fine so far but only thing is it asks the user via pop up if they want to stay on the page or leave and they have to manually click stay. How can I bypass the popup and just automatically choose the stay option.

Any help or ideas would be great on this !! Thanks in advance :)

Comment: You cannot bypass the popup, because it is also fired when the user manually tries to leave. And it would be too easy to abuse on malicious sites if it could be bypassed programmatically.

You will have to find another strategy to prevent your flash from redirecting.

Comment: hmmm any ideas?

Comment: Really depends on the flash component and how it's coded. If it uses `navigateToURL()` internally, it would seem you are out of luck: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32315379/how-to-prevent-from-javascript-flash-navigatetourl,